Manifest merger failed with multiple errors-[In temporary file]
My gradle plugin version is 7.1.0 and gradle version is 7.6.4.While rebuilding my project I am getting this error. It would be helpful if someone assist me to solve this.I have tried clearing caches and rebuilding again and tried changing the minimum and target sdk version.
description of the issue

Update your androidx.test dependencies to their latest version.

It helped to solve the issue. Thanks a lot

Could you verify that the android:exported attribute is set in your manifest file for the activity tag? Otherwise, it is either true or false.

yes, it is there

This isn't really an answer, it should have been a comment.
